# API Platform - How to add response code in Swagger UI using decorator to add 400, 404, 500 response code so client know the response in adwance

Tags: symfony, decorator, openapi, api-platform.com

I want to add Response code(400,404, 500) for each route in swagger UI using , so that user know in advance what will be the response for these error code.

I am following following link but not sure how can I modify the Response object and can add the response for 400, 404, 401 so on.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification

I am using symfony 5.2 and apiplatfrom 2.6 while writing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Its late to post but I got the solutions for adding response code in my Swagger Ui, it can help some looking for solution.

```
private function setErrorResponseDescriptions(OpenApi $openApi): OpenApi
{
    $schemas = $openApi->getComponents()->getSchemas();

    $schemas['Error'] = [
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => [
            'type' => [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'readOnly' => true,
            ],
            'title' => [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'readOnly' => true,
            ],
            'detail' => [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'readOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $schemas['ValidationError'] = [
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => [
            'type' => [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'readOnly' => true,
            ],
            'title' => [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'readOnly' => true,
            ],
            'detail' => [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'readOnly' => true,
            ],
            'validations' => [
                'type'     => 'array',
                'readOnly' => true,
                'items'    => [
                    'type'       => 'object',
                    'properties' => [
                        'propertyPath' => [
                            'type'     => 'string',
                            'readOnly' => true,
                        ],
                        'message' => [
                            'type'     => 'string',
                            'readOnly' => true,
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($openApi->getPaths()->getPaths() as $path => $pathItem) {
        foreach (['PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'GET'] as $method) {
            $item = $pathItem->{'get' . ucfirst($method)}();

            if ($item) {
                $item->addResponse(
                    new Model\Response(
                        description: 'Unauthorized',
                        content: new \ArrayObject([
                            'application/problem+json' => [
                                'schema' => [
                                    '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/Error',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ])
                    ),
                    '401'
                );
                if ('GET' !== $method) {
                    $item->addResponse(
                        new Model\Response(
                            description: 'Bad request',
                            content: new \ArrayObject([
                                'application/problem+json' => [
                                    'schema' => [
                                        '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/ValidationError',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ])
                        ),
                        '400'
                    );
                } else {
                    $item->addResponse(
                        new Model\Response(
                            description: 'Not Found',
                            content: new \ArrayObject([
                                'application/problem+json' => [
                                    'schema' => [
                                        '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/Error',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ])
                        ),
                        '404'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $openApi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using decorators, you are essentially extending existing service code.
First you are getting path and then set your custom operation in swagger context with the given code.

If you notice the code block:

```
$openApi->getPaths()->addPath('/api/grumpy_pizzas/{id}', $pathItem->withGet(
            $operation->withParameters(array_merge(
                $operation->getParameters(),
                [new Model\Parameter('fields', 'query', 'Fields to remove of the output')]
            ))
        ));
```

The path item take [Operation](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/main/src/OpenApi/Model/Operation.php) object as an argument which has [`withResponses`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/287b79c00addf5215d130406bcb05e94f48c78e6/src/OpenApi/Model/Operation.php#L133) method that can be used to modify any responses that your path generates.
Take this as per-cursor and you can check whole source and see what fits your requirements best. Check source : [PathItem.php](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/287b79c00addf5215d130406bcb05e94f48c78e6/src/OpenApi/Model/PathItem.php#L141)

You can  build response according to [Response](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/main/src/OpenApi/Model/Response.php) object and add it to Operation and to path.

Tip: Any editor with good linter would make your coding easier as it will be able to show you available methods.